# How can I configure VS Code to work with Prettier HTML formatter?

Tags: django, visual-studio-code, prettier

I am trying to have VS Code format my Django HTML files but I am getting:
`There is no document formatter for 'django-html'-files installed`.

The [solution I found on the web](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/65189#issuecomment-455086749) works with Beautify, not Prettier.

How can I make it work with Prettier?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Tedkovsky's answer might technically address the error you're getting, but once you're past that, you'll see that Prettier will mangle your templates since it tries to break long lines containing template tags like `{{ }}` and `{% %}`.

This is because Prettier currently (as of 2021-01-09) doesn't support Jinja or Django templates, and for the time being, it looks like the developers aren't interested in adding this functionality. There are 2 (closed) tickets about it here:

- https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/5581
- https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/5754

I wasn't able to find a plugin for it either, so it doesn't look like there's a solution for using Prettier with Django templates.

edit: I've been following [this thread](https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/automatic-formatting-of-django-templates/341) in the Django forum about autoformatters for Django templates. Perhaps something might materialize there.

later edit: Looks like [djhtml](https://github.com/rtts/djhtml) can handle indentation, although it's separate from Prettier. It doesn't do full autoformatting, though.

even later edit: [djlint](https://djlint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) can also be used for formatting templates

Answer (score 0):

In settings.json, try

```
 "[django-html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "prettier"
      },
```

Comment: That doesn't work. I also tried `"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"` and it does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

djLint worked for me.
refer: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=monosans.djlint

1. Install the djlint extension for VS Code.
2. Add this to your settings.json file: " [html] [django-html] [handlebars] [hbs] [mustache] [jinja] [jinja-html] [nj] [njk] [nunjucks] [twig]": { "editor.defaultFormatter": "monosans.djlint" }
3. Enable the options editor.formatOnSave in your settings.json file.